# Sharepoint Reminder Email

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint list and I want to send out a reminder to the same people once a month for them to update it.  I would like this automated out of SharePoint.  Is there a simple way to do this?  The list of folks receiving  this email will be static.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can create a designer workflow which will pause for 1 month before sending an email and then again pause for one month before sending it again. You can add the pause in a loop which never ends.

Answer (score 1):

**Repeating Workflow**

You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow that sends the email, then pauses and repeats itself.

Note that if you use this approach, you probably want it to be a site workflow rather than a list workflow, so you only have one continually running workflow.

With some third-party add-ons, such as Nintex Workflow, you can schedule a site workflow to run regularly so you wouldn't need the workflow to pause and repeat.

**Custom Timer Job**

Using Visual Studio you can write your own job that will be run by SharePoint's timer service (the same service that executes workflows, alerts, etc). The schedule can be set in SharePoint Central Administration.

**Windows Scheduled Task**

If you have access to the web server on which SharePoint is running, you can schedule a task in the Windows Server task scheduler that executes a custom executable, powershell script, batch file, or anything else that tickles your fancy.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Alerts feature on the custom list for this , on which you can set the time interval 
Regards
Arjun

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSRS, create a blank report and create a subscription for that report. Don't forget to uncheck Include report and Include Link. Just write your own subject and comment (which is body of the email) and mention the users in To field. Choose the schedule and you are good to go.